# Problema con Android Studio en windows 10

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo un problema, instale Android Studio en mi pc con windows 10 64 bits, pero cuando empecé a realizar un proyecto me di cuenta que no se mostraban mis componentes (botones, textos etc en la previsualización, no sé cómo arreglar este problema espero me puedan ayudar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acostumbra agregar el layout a tu pregunta, cual es la configuración de tu build.gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el build.gradle cambia alpha3 por alpha1 con la api 28 como viene originalmente. suerte!!

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: ¡yeah!, gracias solucionaste mi problema, busque soluciones por doquier y no la encontraba. ¿Sabes por qué sucede este error?.

Answer (score 1):

Se publico una pregunta similar:

[No puedo ver nada en la pantalla design. (Android Studio)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172868/no-puedo-ver-nada-en-la-pantalla-design-android-studio/172890#172890)

pero en este caso el error es:

> failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error

te sugiero tener como mínima configuración:

usar:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    ...
}
```

con:

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

y dentro del archivo `build.gradle` localizado en la raíz del proyecto, usar minimo gradle versión 3.0.1:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ....
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: mi configuración es la siguiente (la misma que tengo en Ubuntu 18.04): classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3', classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3, classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' y  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'. Disculpa que lo pongo así horrible. Lo que no entiendo es porqué en Ubuntu sí funciona bien y aquí en windows no :C

Comment: Debe funcionar en Windows sin problema.

Comment: Pues con la novedad que acabo formatear mi máquina y ahora ni en la partición de Ubuntu 18.04 funciona, aplica los cambios en el teléfono pero en la vista previa no.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas veces el problema de rendimiento es porque la versión de la api en el editor es mayor que aquella para la que está diseñada tu app y con bajarla sueles poder ver los elementos, tanto en la vista de diseño como en el preview de la vista de texto del layout.

Puedes bajarla en el menú superior en botón verde de android (API version in editor) en el que dice que estas en la versión 28.

Comment: Gracias ya lo hice, le baje la versión a la mínima que permito pero sigue igual.