# No puedo ver nada en la pantalla design. (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, layout

Acabo de empezar con Android Studio y no me da nada más que problemas.
En principio cuando creo un basic activity project, todo parece ir bien. pero cuando entro en la parte grafica de la pantalla design me aparece esto y no veo nada.

[image: Todo el rato con android...ConstraintLayout]

Y aqui os pongo el trozo de codigo de mi content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Llevo semanas intentando buscar soluciones en Google y no encuentro nada. Porfavor, ¿alguien que me lo pueda solucionar?

Comment: El codigo en texto no en imagen por favor.

Comment: Perdón, es la primera vez que uso esta página también para preguntar, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @EduardoRuizMoreno prueba reiniciando Android Studio,

Comment: @Jorgesys como explico en mi respuesta, en mi caso el error era `Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar...`. De todas maneras, parece que la solución ha sido otra, con lo que el error sería diferente.

Comment: yo tenia el mismo problema. solo pon **Build-Rebuild project** y mira el error que te sale corriges eso y ya te debe funcionar.A mi me salia un error por una letra mayúscula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La línea que provoca que no se pueda construir la vista y al mismo tiempo no pueda verse en la opción **Design** es  **tools:showIn**  ya que no encuentra el **Layout** asignado,  por lo tanto debes verificar la ruta donde se encuentra **content_main** y **activity_main** en caso de compartir la ruta la línea quedaría así:

```
tools:showIn="activity_main"
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha solucionado el problema, con lo tonto que era. De verdad, os debo una a todos por haber invertido vuestro tiempo. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias a tí.. un saludo ^^/

Comment: @KarenMaqueda como sabias que activity_main no se encuentra dentro de layout?  poderes sobrenaturales? :-|

Comment: @Jorgesys por qué al ver el log que marcaba en la opción de Design este       -->**The surrounding layout (@layout/activity_example) did not actually include this layout busqué la línea, investigué un poco y vi que era por la ruta. jajja.. noo no tengo tal poder

Comment: **Revisa la imagen de [mi respuesta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNr1p.png) en realidad se tiene el error pero puede mostrar sin problema la prevista**, yo sugiero actualización de minimo API 26 @EduardoRuizMoreno

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo solucione asi:

```
En res/values/style.xml
```

solo modifique esa parte el resto del codigo debe quedar igual como el que se generó.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto parece ser un bug del template de Android Studio. La verdad es que hasta que no lo he probado, no estaba seguro de cual era el problema.

Si te fijas en tu propia captura de pantalla, te dice que hay un error. Si lo despliegas, probablemente el error sea este:

> Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio

Tras una búsqueda extensa, al parecer ese error se soluciona de la siguiente manera:

- Ve al archivo `/res/values/styles.xml`
- En ese archivo de estilos, debes añadir `Base` antes del tema. Es dedir, modifica:

  ```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>
  ```

  por

  ```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>
  ```

Recarga la vista y ya deberías ver en el designer los componentes.

*Referencia: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611939/579895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611939/579895_)*

Answer (score 0):

La vista de diseño en ocasiones no se puede representar (rendering), esto ocurre cuando encuentra un error en el layout, personalmente creo que puede ser también debido a memoria y error de la IDE.

Algunas versiones Android Studio incluso presentan problemas con el `ConstraintLayout`, de hecho a ti te muestra un warning.

Puedes reiniciar tu IDE y en ocasiones esto se resuelve.

**Pero te sugiero actualizar a la versión `Android Studio 3.1.2`** ahora ya no tengo problema con esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso se muestra la vista de diseño del layout aún cuando existen problemas al representarlo visualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Actualización:**

Esta es la mínima configuración que puede resolver el problema:

use:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    ...
}
```

with:

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

y dentro del archivo `build.gradle` localizado en la raíz del proyecto, usar minimo gradle versión 3.0.1:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ....
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero estoy en la versión 3.1.3 y me sale ese error. de hecho los avisos que me salen son. Render problem: Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.  y tambien me sale un problema con las variables privates. Using private sources: The resource @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as private in com.android.support:design  Private resources should not be referenced; the may not be present everywhere, and even where they are they may disappear without notice.  To fix this, copy the resource into your own project.

Comment: @EduardoRuizMoreno actualiza a usar la API 26 en tu configuración. El error como vez se muestra pero eso no debe impedir se muestre la prevista, claro se mostraría sin los elementos que tienen error, pero no se evitaría mostrar toda la prevista..