# Render problem en android studio, no muestra componentes

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: captura]

Acabo de crear el proyecto y no muestra mi action bar, ni el textview que acabo de poner, me manda ese mensaje de render problem, espero puedan ayudarme, es la primera vez que me sucede esto, y quiza tenga que ver con que es el primer proyecto que creo en esta nueva pc

Comment: Posible pregunta duplicada en [https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172804/18182]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo solucione(ponele).En la carpeta app>res>values>styles.xml
Cambiando esto:

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

por:

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

lo que haces es que no se vea la action bar.Pero no lo terminas de los solucionar.Pero podes seguir trabajando.
La otra es entrar por Gradle Scripts>build.gradle(Module:app):
La linea

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

cambias el 3 por un 1 y lo sincroniza

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: la verdad es que estoy empezando con esto de Android y como el compañero creador del mensaje, me paso lo mismo, cree mi primer proyecto y me salio ese error, espero que sigas brindando ayuda en el mundo del internet, muy agradecido, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Busca en el directorio y cambia la línea de código tal como aparece en la imágen
no olvide dar clic en Sync Now, con esto se debe de solucionar tu problema

[image: busca el directorio y cambia la línea de código]

[image: no olvide dar clic en Sync Now]