# Problema con Layout

Tags: android

Muy Buenas, Estoy comenzando a usar android studio 3.1

El problema es que cuando quiero agregar un elemento como un texto o un botton no lo puedo visualizar en la pantalla del Layout.

Cual puede ser el problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, como podemos saber cual es el problema si no se agrega el layout, te sugiero agregarlo. Revisa [ask] para saber como crear preguntas y tengas excelentes respuestas. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Posible duplicado en [https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172804/18182]

Comment: **Agrega tu layout por favor.**